Script in AppScripts in Google Sheets dont work (Discord embed + google sheet)
I do script in google sheets, then set trigger. On my test table it works clearly, but on other table it get error.
function onEdit(e) {
  var discordUrl = "MYWEBHOOK_URL";

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  const column1 = sheet.getRange("H:H").getColumn() - 1;
  const column2 = sheet.getRange("I:I").getColumn() - 1;
  const column3 = sheet.getRange("J:J").getColumn() - 1;
  var arrmessage =[];
  for (var i = 3; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][column2] !== "" || data[i][column3] !== "") {
      arrmessage.push({name: `${data[i][column1]}`,value:"",inline: true});
      arrmessage.push({name: `${data[i][column2]}`,value:"",inline: true});
      arrmessage.push({name: `${data[i][column3]}`,value:"",inline: true});
    }
  }
  Logger.log(arrmessage);

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "content": "Here it is",
      "embeds": [{
        "color": 16711680,
        "title": "Best player",
        "fields": arrmessage,
        "footer": {
          "text": "TRN CLNX"
        }
      }]
    })
  };

  try {
    if (sheetName === "Sheet2") {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, options);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Message is empty or contains 'undefined'. No request sent.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error occurred: " + error.toString());
  }
}

This one with status complete
ERROR1:Message is empty or contains 'undefined'. No request sent. 

This one with status uncomplete
ERROR2: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSheet')<br>
    at onEdit(Код:7:23) 

ERROR 3: Information Error occurred: Exception: You are not allowed to call UrlFetchApp.fetch user. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request.

I'm trying to reproduce part of table in embeded message in discord (with trigger "when change")
Here is  my prod table:

Here is my test workable table:

The result of test table:

All at all i want to sent message to discord when my table changed

The question needs to include more details. Please briefly describe the spreadsheet and include sample data for both tables.

Using indeterminate ranges like "H:H" does not work well with apps script trying using H1:H + sheet.getLastRow() or sheet.getRange( 1,8,sheet.getLastRow())

@Wicket im add more info

@Cooper My case works, but thanks i will try

While links to external files might be helful, questions should be self-contained. This means that all the relevant details should be included directly in the question.

@Wicket Oh, sorry its my first question and i just ctrl+v (stackoverflow convert it to links)

I didn't noticed that the links pointed to images. Images are OK for showing a relevant UI element / layout, or something that can't be expressed using code or words, however, when the intention is to show a simple table or add sample data, they should be added as text. You might use use markdown to format data as table.

@Wicket Aaa, I understand what you mean

The message that was referred  as "Error 1",

Message is empty or contains 'undefined'. No request sent."

It is not an execution time error. It's a log message printed to the execution logs because sheetName is not equal to Sheet2. Please ensure that the edit sheet is named Sheet2 or change the literal in the if statement accordingly.
The message that was referred to as "Error 2" likely occurred because onEdit was run using the Apps Script Editor Run button. This causes the variable e to be undefined. The simplest way to test the onEdit function is by editing the spreadsheet using the Google Sheets web app UI. This assigns an instance of the edit event object to e. See How can I test a trigger function in GAS?.
Error 3 is straightforward. Add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request to the OAuth scopes in the Apps Script manifest. For details about how to edit the manifest, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests.

I know that my first error is my Logger.log, its just for info. Thanks for info about undefined, i ll check. Ive already change my manifest, thanks.

The authorization error you are getting is because of the onEdit() function being a simple trigger.
Simple triggers cannot access API services that require authorization.
Change the function's name and set an installable trigger to run the target function on edit events.

This question does not mention an authorization error related to onEdit being a simple trigger. The error referred to as Error 3 concerns using UrlFetchApp, which works with simple triggers.

Thanks, ive already try to rewrite into installable trigger, because i need to call API method(im not mention it in my q), but its true that UrlFetchApp works with simple triggers

Here is the workable example, i change manifest file and one of the main error was that discord embeded message support <=25 fields
function onEdit(e) {

  var discordUrl = "WEBHOOK_URL";

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  
  if (sheetName !== "Sheet2") {
    Logger.log("Its not Sheet2");
    return;
  }

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  const column1 = 7; // H - number
  const column2 = 8; // I - nick
  const column3 = 9; // J - sec

  var numberField = "";
  var nickField = "";
  var secondsField = "";
  
  for (var i = 3; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][column1] !== "" && data[i][column2] !== "" && data[i][column3] !== "") {
      numberField += `${data[i][column1]}\n`;
      nickField += `${data[i][column2]}\n`;
      secondsField += `${data[i][column3]}\n`;
    }
  }
  var userIdMention= `${data[3][column2]}`;
  var userId = userIdMention.replace(/[<@>]/g, '');
  var topPlayer = `1. ${data[3][column2]} - ${data[3][column3]}`;
  var avatarUrl = getDiscordUserAvatarUrl(userId);
  Logger.log("Avatar URL: " + avatarUrl);
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "embeds": [{
        "color": 16711680,
        "description": "# The best \n" + topPlayer,
        "fields": [
          {name: "#", value: numberField, inline: true},
          {name: "Nick", value: nickField, inline: true},
          {name: "Sec", value: secondsField, inline: true}
        ],
        "footer": {
          "text": "VALF CLNX"
        },
        "thumbnail": {
          "url": avatarUrl
        }, // Include the avatar URL here
      }]
    })
  };

  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, options);
    Logger.log("Answer Discord:");
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.toString());
  }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
